# How to access a file from python when the OS opens the script to handle opening that file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I open an HTML file, for instance, I have it set such that it opens in Chrome. Now if I set a given python script to be the thing that opens a given filetype, how do I access this file in the script? Where is it available from?

Comment: If we call the file being opened `B` and the script doing the opening is called `A`, are you asking how `A` can access `B` or how `B` can access `A`?

Comment: How `A` can access `B`. (Would the reverse make sense? Trying to figure out when that would be applicable)....but yeah you see why this was slightly difficult to google.

Comment: You can't make a "python **script** to be the thing that opens a given filetype" when accessing the file, it will simply return a error. Perhaps maybe converting the script to an exe might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a file, the operating system starts the responsible opener program and passes the file(s) to be opened as [command line arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments):

```
path/to/opener_executable path/to/file1_to_be_opened path/to/file2_to_be_opened ...
```

You can access the command line arguments through [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) in your python script. A minimal example:

```
import sys

print("I'm supposed to open the following file(s):")
print('\n'.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: So K Dawg's comment above is inaccurate, a script can handle this situation without being .exe'ified ?

Comment: @Aerovistae Yes, you can set a certain file type to be opened through the command `python.exe my_opener_script.py`, which will launch your script and pass the parameters to it. Or worst case scenario, you can make a `.bat` script that launches your python script and passes on the parameters.

Comment: @Rawing yup you'd have to make a bat script. Thus my first statement stands correct, you cannot assign a python *script* as a file opener in Windows...

Comment: @KDawG Pretty sure it's possible without a `.bat`, though you might have to edit your registry manually to put in `python.exe my_script.py "%1"` or something like that.

Comment: Well yeah you could even make it a .exe file. which is probably even easier. Or write a simple c++ application to pass the file opener's argument to the python script.

Answer (score 0):

To prove `Rawing`'s point, on Linux, you "open with Other Application" and select your python script, which you made executable.
`sys.argv` provides the name of the script as argument 0 and thereafter a list of any other parameters.

myopener.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os
x=os.open('/home/rolf/myopener.output',os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT)
xx = os.fdopen(x,'w+')
y=str(sys.argv)
xx.write(y)
xx.close()
```

Opening the file abc.ddd with `myopener.py` creates the file `myopener.output` contents:

```
['/home/rolf/myopener.py', '/home/rolf/abc.ddd']
```